# Problem compiling java on CentOS 5.6

Tags: java, bash, compiler-construction, centos

For windows I just used a batch script to compile my program:

```
@echo off
title Building...
echo Building Server - please wait...
echo ---------------------------------------

set javac="C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\javac.exe"

set libs=bin;

set dirs=src\server\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\commands\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\components\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\item\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\net\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\randomevent\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\minigames\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\minigames\trawler\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\minigames\trawler\game\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\quests\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\skills\runecrafting\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\skills\slayer\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\tasks\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\tasks\net\*.java
set dirs=%dirs% src\server\threading\*.java

%javac% -classpath %libs% %dirs% -d bin
echo ---------------------------------------
title Buld complete.
echo Build complete.
pause
```

Everything compiles fine.
So I move my project onto my CentOS VPS and try to compile with a bash script

```
echo Building...
echo Building Server - please wait...
echo ---------------------------------------

libs=bin
dirs=src/server/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/commands/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/components/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/item/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/net/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/randomevent/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/minigames/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/minigames/trawler/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/minigames/trawler/game/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/quests/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/skills/runecrafting/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/skills/slayer/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/tasks/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/tasks/net/*.java
dirs=$dirs src/server/threading/*.java

javac -classpath $libs $dirs -d bin
echo ---------------------------------------
title Buld complete.
echo Build complete.
```

And I must be doing something wrong.  I get these errors:

```
: command not founde 4:
: No such file or directory/server/commands/*.java
: No such file or directory/server/components/*.java
: No such file or directory/server/item/*.java
: No such file or directoryc/server/net/*.java
: No such file or directoryc/server/randomevent/*.java
: No such file or directoryc/server/minigames/*.java
: No such file or directoryc/server/minigames/trawler/*.java
: No such file or directoryc/server/minigames/trawler/game/*.java
: No such file or directoryc/server/quests/*.java
: No such file or directoryc/server/skills/runecrafting/*.java
: No such file or directoryc/server/skills/slayer/*.java
: No such file or directoryc/server/tasks/*.java
: No such file or directoryc/server/tasks/net/*.java
: No such file or directoryc/server/threading/*.java
: command not founde 21:
javac: invalid flag: src/server/*.java
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Is there a syntax error?

Comment: I strongly suggest you try out Apache Ant. It is made for things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotation marks around the right hand side of all of your assignments, e.g.

`dirs="$dirs src/server/commands/*.java"`

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why the wildcards aren't being expanded, but the `dirs =` lines aren't valid syntax; you need to quote the right hand side. Given the odd error messages, I'd question whether `bash` was being used to execute the script. Are you sure it is?

In any case, oy. This is a crazy way to compile your code. Either use `Ant`  or `make`, and they'll make your life a lot easier.

Comment: the error messages are because bash will read the assigment up to the space and then attempt to execute everything after the space as if it were a command

Comment: But it still would expand the wildcards first, that's the thing. I don't know why it wouldn't.